# How to add class on hover using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have anchor tag with data-value attribute whenever user clicks on the hyperlink I am storing data-value in local storage I want to add active class to the hyperlink which matches data-value with local storage.

HTML code,

```
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Fitted bed Sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/fitted-bed-sheet"> Fitted bed Sheet  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Flat bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/flat-bed-sheet"> Flat bed sheet  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Full bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/full-bed-sheets"> Full bed sheets   </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twin bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twin-bed-sheet"> Twin bed sheet  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Twinxl bed sheets  " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/twinxl-bed-sheets"> Twinxl bed sheets   </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Queen bed sheet " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/queen-bed-sheet"> Queen bed sheet  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-bed-sheets"> King bed sheets  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Cal king bed sheets " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/cal-king-bed-sheets"> Cal king bed sheets  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Duvet covers " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/duvet-covers"> Duvet covers  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Bed skirts " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/bed-skirts"> Bed skirts  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Standard Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/standard-pillow-cases"> Standard Pillow cases  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="King Pillow cases " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/king-pillow-cases"> King Pillow cases  </a> </div>
<div class="flItems"><a class="category_filter" data-value="Pillow shells " href="http://192.168.1.156/eles/bed-linen/pillow-shells"> Pillow shells  </a> </div>
```

Jquery Code,

```
$(".categories_fltrs").hover(function(){
    //alert("adhfdba");
        var clickedvalue = localStorage.getItem("clickedLink");
        //alert(clickedvalue);
        if(clickedvalue)
        {
            //alert("fgjdf");
            //$("data-value='" + clickedvalue + "']").addClass("active");
             $('a[data-value = '+clickedvalue+'].category_filter').addClass('active');
        }
});
```

Comment: are you wanting to change the colour of the hovered item, or the one that is stored in local storage.  If the latter, why are you only changing it on hover of any categories_fltrs links, why not change it when it is clicked and also when the page is loaded?  What has the hovering got to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work:

```
$(".category_filter").hover(function(){
    //alert("adhfdba");
    var clickedvalue = localStorage.getItem("clickedLink");
    //alert(clickedvalue);
    if(clickedvalue && clickedvalue == $(this).attr("data-value"))
    {
        //alert("fgjdf");
        //$("data-value='" + clickedvalue + "']").addClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Just make sure you also remove the active class accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I'd say use `$(this)` this instead of `$('a[data-value = '+clickedvalue+'].category_filter')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".categories_fltrs").hover(function(){
    //alert("adhfdba");
        var clickedvalue = localStorage.getItem("clickedLink");
        //alert(clickedvalue);
        if(clickedvalue)
        {
            //alert("fgjdf");
            $(".category_filter[data-value='"+clickedvalue+"']").addClass("active");
             // $(this).addClass('active');
        }
});
```

Got it working!!! Thx all for your inputs...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to style links that have been visited differently, it's best to use the :visited pseudo class and avoid using javascript.

Comment: thanks for your reply we want to add the class when page refresh also that is why we storing local storage.